# How can I use FSDK_LoadImageFromBuffer Function in FSDK (Face SDK) by Luxand on Android?

Tags: java, android, face-detection, face-recognition

I created an android studio project that uses Luxand Face SDK to take a photo of a person and returns the detected face and save the data in a file so that the user can be recognised later. How can I use **FSDK_LoadImageFromBuffer Function** on **byte[]**? I tried many ways to use it but every time i want to use the **FSDK_DetectFace Function** it is not detecting anything.